# (React) Remove Element from an Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, formik

Hope you're well. I've looked around quite some time and have been unable to find a solution to this problem I'm having. The problem that I am having is that I cannot remove an item from an array that is display. The reason that I can't remove it is because once the element is displayed within the child component, and then brought back into the parent component, it not longer has the same *shape* as it did when it went into the child component. It goes into the child component as an array, and It is coming out of it as an object, with additional layers of sophistication. Can someone help me understand why that object (stared) is changing its shape, and how I can preserve its shape as an array, and then remove elements from it?

I have been unable to preserve the array as an array when it returns to the parent component.

I've looked to a number of resources and cannot figure it out. I'm trying to remove an object from an array so it will be removed from react in real time. the Problem is, is that prevState.mapped(object) is not being recognized as an array when it comes back from the component piece that is rendering the individual cards that render each object within the array. I believe this has something to do with formik. I have tried the following:

- I have tried to set up a seperate variable with 'prevState.etc' as an array and then remove it from that, and then put that into state.
- I have attempted to work on the array within the component *as it is being rendered,* but this is not working either. I did this figuring that once it comes back through to the parent component, maybe that will help me work with it as it will have the proper shape.

I've looked around a bit, but I must not be asking the right question, because I'm not getting an answer as to why the prevState object I'm working with isn't an array once it comes back through to the parent component. I do not doubt that the solution to the problem is fairly simple. I have pasted the below relevant code: It is pasted in the sequence it is run:

**1.) This section of the code makes an AXIOS call, and when that call is successfully made, that data is then filtered into a card component.**

```
class Organizations extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { organizations: [], mappedOrgs: [] };
  }

  //ORG LOAD
  componentDidMount() {
    paginatedList(0, 8).then(this.onOrgSuccess);
  }

  //ORG CALL SUCCESS

  onOrgSuccess = (config) => {
    let organizations = config.item.pagedItems;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        mappedOrgs: organizations.map(this.mapOrg),
      };
    }, this.stateChanged);
  };

  mapOrg = (Organization) => (
    _logger(Organization, "ORGANIZATION, ORGANIZATION"),
    (
      <OrgCard
        Organization={Organization}
        key={Organization.id}
        editOrganization={this.editOrganization}
        deleteFunction={this.deleteFunction}
      />
    )
  );
```

**2.) The below are the functions within the card component. The 'Handle Delete' function also does go through the component, as a result, I have depicted it as well. It is obviously a part of the component that is being rendered overall.**

```
const OrgCard = ({ Organization, editOrganization, deleteFunction }) => {
  //OPERATIONAL FUNCTIONS
  _logger(Organization);

  //DELETE
  const OrgDelete = () => {
    deleteOrg(Organization.id).then(deleteSuccess).catch(deleteToastFail);
  };

  //SUCCESS FUNCTIONS

  const deleteSuccess = () => {
    deleteFunction(Organization);
  };

    <Button
      onClick={OrgDelete}
      className="btn-danger btn-lg center"
      align="center"
    >
      Delete
    </Button>
```

**The below is the function where the removal from the array is supposed to take place. This is the parent component of what you see above, and is within the same body of code as the code body that is numbered "1". The offending code has two stars around it, it obviously does not have two stars in the actual code.**

```
  deleteFunction = (deletedOrg) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const indexOfOrg = **prevState.mappedOrgs**.findIndex(
        (Org) => Org.id === deletedOrg.id
      );
      let updatedOrgs = [...prevState.mappedOrgs];
      if (indexOfOrg >= 0) {
        updatedOrgs.slice(indexOfOrg, 1);
      }
      _logger(updatedOrgs);

      return { mappedOrgs: updatedOrgs };
    }, this.stateChanged);
  };
```

I do not know Formik, and props validation very well, so I'm going to post that below as well incase that is some how relevant.

This is the props validation within the code body numbered as '1'

```
Organizations.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func,
  }),
  findIndex: PropTypes.func,
  deleteFunction: PropTypes.checkPropTypes({
    deletedOrg: PropTypes.number,
    mappedOrgs: PropTypes.array,
    findIndex: PropTypes.func,
    updatedOrgs: PropTypes.array,
    splice: PropTypes.func,
    indexOfOrg: PropTypes.number,
  }),
};
```

I've been trying so many things, I even have props validation within the card rendering as well. In this case, this is in '2'.

```
OrgCard.propTypes = {
  Organization: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    OrganizationTypeId: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    logo: PropTypes.string,
    locationId: PropTypes.number,
    phone: PropTypes.string,
    siteUrl: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  deleteOrg: PropTypes.func,
  deleteFunction: PropTypes.func,
  editOrganization: PropTypes.func,
};
```

**This is the first body of code.**

```
class Organizations extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { organizations: [], mappedOrgs: [] };
  }

  //ORG LOAD
  componentDidMount() {
    paginatedList(0, 8).then(this.onOrgSuccess);
  }

  //ORG CALL SUCCESS

  onOrgSuccess = (config) => {
    let organizations = config.item.pagedItems;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        mappedOrgs: organizations.map(this.mapOrg),
      };
    }, this.stateChanged);
  };

  mapOrg = (Organization) => (
    _logger(Organization, "ORGANIZATION, ORGANIZATION"),
    (
      <OrgCard
        Organization={Organization}
        key={Organization.id}
        editOrganization={this.editOrganization}
        deleteFunction={this.deleteFunction}
      />
    )
  );

  //DELETE

  deleteFunction = (deletedOrg) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const indexOfOrg = prevState.mappedOrgs.findIndex(
        (Org) => Org.id === deletedOrg.id
      );
      let updatedOrgs = [...prevState.mappedOrgs];
      if (indexOfOrg >= 0) {
        updatedOrgs.slice(indexOfOrg, 1);
      }
      _logger(updatedOrgs);

      return { mappedOrgs: updatedOrgs };
    }, this.stateChanged);
  };

  //MAP ORG


  editOrganization = (Organization) => {
    this.props.history.push(
      `/organization/${Organization.id}/edit`,
      Organization
    );
  };
  //RENDER
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-12">
        <div className="row">{this.state.mappedOrgs}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Organizations.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func,
  }),
  findIndex: PropTypes.func,
  deleteFunction: PropTypes.checkPropTypes({
    deletedOrg: PropTypes.number,
    mappedOrgs: PropTypes.array,
    findIndex: PropTypes.func,
    updatedOrgs: PropTypes.array,
    splice: PropTypes.func,
    indexOfOrg: PropTypes.number,
  }),
};

export default Organizations;
```

**This is the second body of code.**

```
const OrgCard = ({ Organization, editOrganization, deleteFunction }) => {
  //OPERATIONAL FUNCTIONS
  _logger(Organization);

  //DELETE
  const OrgDelete = () => {
    deleteOrg(Organization.id).then(deleteSuccess).catch(deleteToastFail);
  };

  //SUCCESS FUNCTIONS

  const deleteSuccess = () => {
    deleteFunction(Organization);
  };

  //FAIL FUNCTION

  const deleteToastFail = () => {
    toast.error("Delete Error", {
      closeOnClick: true,
      position: "top-center",
    });
  };

  //EDIT

  const handleEdit = () => {
    editOrganization(Organization);
  };

  return (
    <Card className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      {" "}
      <CardHeader style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} className="text-center">
        {Organization.name}
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <CardImg src={Organization.logo} />
        {/* <CardText>
          <span>{Organization.description.slice(0, 120)}</span>
        </CardText> */}
        <CardText>
          <span>{Organization.id}</span>
        </CardText>
        <Button
          onClick={handleEdit}
          className="btn-sucess btn-lg center"
          align="center"
        >
          Edit
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={OrgDelete}
          className="btn-danger btn-lg center"
          align="center"
        >
          Delete
        </Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

OrgCard.propTypes = {
  Organization: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    OrganizationTypeId: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    logo: PropTypes.string,
    locationId: PropTypes.number,
    phone: PropTypes.string,
    siteUrl: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  deleteOrg: PropTypes.func,
  deleteFunction: PropTypes.func,
  editOrganization: PropTypes.func,
};

export default OrgCard;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any code snippets that suggest the type of `this.state.mappedOrgs` would have changed. Do you mind just updating your question with the *entire* component code for both parent and child so we may better see what updates the state in the parent for `mappedOrgs` to no longer be an array?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added the complete bodies of code that you requested, in their complete form. My guess was that it had something to do with formik. I also added a picture at the bottom of the post to give you a clear idea of how it is coming through. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Is this your complete code? I don't see (1) anywhere where a form or Formik is used, and (2) anything changing `this.state.mappedOrgs` to anything other than an array. Why are you storing react components in state? This is an anti-pattern. Are you receiving an error in the `deleteFunction` in `Organizations` component? An error at all, anywhere? If so, please include the error text and any stacktrace included with it from the console log, and the exact steps taken to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the solution that I wound up coming up with for this problem. Hope it is helpful to someone else.

```
  removeFromArray = (deletedCompany) => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const indexOfCompany = prevState.Companies.findIndex(
    (removeCompany) => removeCompany.id === deletedCompany.id
  );
  if (indexOfCompany === -1) {
    this.toastErrorDelete();
    return;
  } else {
    const updatedCompanies = [...prevState.Companies];
    updatedCompanies.splice(indexOfCompany, 1);
    return { Companies: updatedCompanies };
  }
}, this.clearForm());
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify why you're passing the array from the child back to the parent?

I believe the proper structure is the parent stores the array in its state. It can then pass the array to the child. It should also pass a delete function to the child (this function should take an index as an argument). This function is defined in the parent. The parent passes the function to the child by passing the function's name. The child, if it wants to delete an item from the array, would then call that function and pass it the index of the item to delete. The function (which is in the parent) would then delete that item from its array (which is stored in that parent's state). This would automatically cause the array displayed in the child to update as well.

The idea is that the array should only ever be passed from the parent to the child. The parent should handle all array manipulations. The child should only ever pass information *about* the array to the parent by calling a function (which was passed to it from the parent) with a relevant argument, such as an index.